# Cannot Login to Apache server which is also FTP server?

Tags: apache-2.4, htpasswd

I have created a `.master-passwd` file with help of `htpasswd` and also added few users with a password to the file. My Problem is that some users who were added later date can not access the FTP server. Why would FTP server access be unavailable and how can I fix this?

Thanks
Pritesh

Comment: Apache and FTP are two different services and the access you have provided for users of the Apache services (HTTP/HTTPS) may not be configured for the FTP services. You probably need to check /etc/passwd on the system and look at how your FTP service is configured.

Comment: Thanks for replying, The FTP service is running on Apache and we have never face this situation till last Monday when we added couples of users.